# AWS EC2 networking

Tags: ubuntu, networking, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, routing

I've been trying to understand how exactly networking works for EC2 instances, more specifically I'm coming from on-prem infrastructure where I had dedicated networking devices (switches/routers) where would manage pretty much everything I (sysadmin) would require for my servers.

I would have the traditional setup where the servers would have multiple NICs, each attached to different subnets in order to isolate specific services. These subnets would have DHCP enabled so I wouldn't interfere with the interfaces more than changing a few parameters or occasionally changing some routing rules in order to enable additional connectivity for specific cases.

For AWS EC2 from what I could gather each subnet is connected to a VPC, which also has a routing table and handles everything related to routing which hasn't proven as an issue up until now however I have the following specific case:

I would need an EC2 instance with multiple NICs which have EIPs attached to them (1:1), the reason being I would need dedicated IPs for different services on the instances where each one of them would need to be reachable and to transmit data through the dedicated IP. I created the new interfaces and associated them with the EC2 + allocated new EIPs and attached them to the new NICs (each NIC in a different subnet inside the same VPC). All easily done, however when looking inside my EC2 (ubuntu 22.04) I could see that the interfaces are up however they don't have any private and/or public IPs associated so I ran **dhclient** in order to get through DHCP my allocated IPs. After doing so I ended up having the expected IPs but also new default routes. For example for 3 NICs I ended up having 3 default routes which obviously was screwing up everything networking wise. I had also tried to create route tables dedicated per NIC like this:

```
ip rule add from $ip_address lookup $table_id
ip route add default via $gateway dev $iface table $table_id
```

I also tried to switch from using dhclient to recreating the netplan config file with something similar to (yes I also disabled cloud-init netplan):

```
network:
  version: 2
  ethernets:
    eth0:   
      dhcp4: true

    eth1:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-routes: false

    eth2:
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp4-overrides:
        use-routes: false

done
```

But the issue with this fix would be that the NICs are now up however the EIPs aren't reachable as there are no routes on the instance in order to access the services.

My question would be how would you normally treat such a case in AWS where I would need multiple public IPs where each one of them would serve different services and yes, I would say it's mandatory to have multiple public IPs.

Thank you!

Comment: There's really 2 questions here in one; if you are running on-prem with multiple public IP addresses on an Ubuntu host then you're going to have to do some routing magic to reply on the same interface came in on (usually done with tagging). As for the VPC thing...you need to add NAT gateways. But I'm very surprised at the objective if using different addresses for the same host - this sounds like the XY problem.

Comment: I would be interested for both cases to be honest but firstly the AWS part. would i need a NAT gateway per EIP? is this something that can also be done at linux level as I might switch at one point to Azure based on my requirements or even have to implement this for both platforms.

Comment: *"But the issue with this fix would be that the NICs are now up however the EIPs aren't reachable as there are no routes on the instance in order to access the services."* I'm not sure what this sentence means, so I'm unclear on the issue you are trying to resolve.  EIP to private IP is 1:1 static NAT, handled transparently by the VPC's Internet Gateway (not NAT Gateway -- those are not needed when a machine has an EIP).  The IP stack on the EC2 instance is never aware of the EIP and only aware of the corresponding private IP.

Comment: You could also consider a aws elb where the public ips are associated with the load balancer and the load balancer forwards the traffic to the proper backend